# google Visualization Line Chart origin

Tags: visualization, google-visualization

Hello I have a Google Visualisation Line chart like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Week');

        data.addColumn('number', 'Points');

        data.addRows([['12/26/2011 12:00:00 AM', 0], ['1/2/2012 12:00:00 AM', 0], ['1/9/2012 12:00:00 AM', 0], ['1/16/2012 12:00:00 AM', 0]]);



        var options = {

            width: 800, height: 400,

            hAxis: {title: 'Week'},

            vAxis: {title: 'Points', minValue: 0, baseline: 0},

            title: 'Activity'

        };



        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

    }

</script>



<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

How can I set the vertical axis to start from 0 (now it starts from -1 and goes to 1) (my vertical axis values are always>0). Also they are always natural numbers how can I make the vertical axes to only show natural numbers on the scale (no fractional numbers)?
Thank you,
Bogdan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `var options` , you can add this :

```
      vAxis: {
        viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
        viewWindow: {
          //max: 8000,
          min: 0,
        },
        gridlines: {
          count: 18,  //set kind of step (max-min)/count
        }
      }
```